# Is it possible to do this: MyInt.CustomMethod

Tags: c#, methods, int

I am making a game in C#, where you have ammo and a max capacity of it.

Is it possible to make some kind of method like this

`ammoInt.Maxed;`

so that i can use it like this:

`if (ammoInt.Maxed == true) etc.`

to check if `ammo` int is equal to `maxAmmoInt`?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the input, but one last question: do the extension *have* to be in a seperate class?

Comment: Look at extension methods

Comment: Yes extension methods need to be in a seperate class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for `int`. Like:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool Maxed(this int parameter)
    {
        return parameter > 100;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
if(ammoInt.Maxed())
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. Extension methods provide this in .Net. But this is bad design.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static public bool IsMaxed( this int value )
    {
        return value > 50; // or whatever
    }
}

int thing = 10;
bool result = thing.IsMaxed( );
```

This allows you to call that method on any int object. But like I said, you should probably reconsider the design of that, as that is a hack.

Comment: Why do you say that it is a hack? And the class has to be static also, FYI

Comment: You really shouldn't be adding extensions to primitive types. In this context it may make sense to see if this int is at it's max. But this method doesn't really apply to ALL integers in the project. So at any random point he could be developing, have an integer, and see it has an IsMaxed method. No context there.

Comment: You should specify that in your answer as this wouldn't be a hack if all ints in the OP's project have this property. That is why I had to ask the Q...it needs to be looked at from multiple angles :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I see it is that you have two options.

1) Create a wrapper class that has a `bool` property that check if its value if greater than `100`

```
public class Ammo
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public bool Maxed 
    {
       get
       {
         return Value > 100;
       }
    }
}
```

2) You can create an Extension Method

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
   public static bool Maxed(this int value)
   {
      return value> 100;
   }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even call it `MyAmmoInt`, just call it `Ammo`.  (Also, it probably makes sense as an immutable struct, rather than a mutable class, even though making it a struct (properly) would take a fair bit more typing.

Comment: @Servy I totally agree, it was more for demonstration that it is in fact a simple wrapper class.

Comment: My point though is that you shouldn't think of it so much as a wrapper, but as the representation of "ammo", which just happens to have nothing more to it than an int.  Conceptually it's not a wrapper, it's just everything there is to know about ammo.